# Index name too long attachinary/postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I keep getting this error after installing the ruby gem for `Attachinary` and trying to run `db:migrate`:

```
Index name 'index_attachinary_files_on_attachinariable_type_and_attachinariable_id' on table 'attachinary_files' is too long; the limit is 63 characters
```

I've been searching and searching for a solution and of course heard about giving a name to the index to avoid the generated one but it doesn't seem to be working. There is actually a name field already that says:

```
'name: by_scoped_parent'
```

Here is the full line in my migrate file:

```
add_index :attachinary_files, [:attachinariable_type, :attachinariable_id, :scope], name: 'by_scoped_parent'
```

Here is the content of the migration file:

```
class CreateAttachinaryTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :attachinary_files do |t|
      t.references :attachinariable, polymorphic: true
      t.string :scope

      t.string :public_id
      t.string :version
      t.integer :width
      t.integer :height
      t.string :format
      t.string :resource_type
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :attachinary_files, [:attachinariable_type, :attachinariable_id, :scope], name: 'by_scoped_parent'
  end
end
```

Note: Don't have any doublon in my *db/migrate* folder. The last migration files went perfectly well.

I'm currently learning Rails so I hope someone can help and forgive me if it's a silly question .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you generate two migrations??

Comment: Hey @AlejandroMontilla! It actually stops before migrating

Comment: here is what I get in the terminal after rails db:migrate --trace:

'** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20170614155451 CreateAttachinaryTables: migrating ==========================
-- create_table(:attachinary_files)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
Index name 'index_attachinary_files_on_attachinariable_type_and_attachinariable_id' on table 'attachinary_files' is too long..'

Comment: Please list all the files in the `/app/db/migrate/` directory. Add that information to the Question (with the edit link).

Comment: Don't have any doublon in it only on related to this specific migration

Comment: Ok, Let me try to explain myself.. I think you have two migration pending (the first one with the name too long, and the second with the shorter name), that is what in asking you about the files in that directory.

Comment: Alright so if that is the case I should have two migration files in `/db/migrate` am I right? Cause I only have one regarding this migration :/

Comment: Ok.. and you are sure that you save your work in that file?

Comment: All sure.. I found a lot of stuff regarding this problem but it always says that to avoid it you have to add a proper name to the index. Which I tried several time but maybe I'm missing something cause it has a name already.
Gonna add the code that is inside the migration file to my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error due to this line in the migration:

```
t.references :attachinariable, polymorphic: true
```

By default index is true. If you don't want this index (which seems like is the case as you are adding scope also later on in the index) then make index: false:

```
t.references :attachinariable, polymorphic: true, index: false
```

Or add a name:

```
t.references :attachinariable, polymorphic: true, index: {name: 'name of your choice here'}
```

Comment: Hi Archana! It worked perfectly thanks so much. Can you tell me a bit more about my problem? I've made some researches on the web and I didn't find anyone with this issue (related to this particular gem). The file was generate after typing `rails attachinary:install:migrations` so I didn't really choose anything. Why would it happen to me? Also the "name" parameter that is already in the "add_index" line isn't supposed to be the index name?  Anyway thanks again!!

Comment: @ThomasCailhol Whenever there is a `reference` (a foreign key) in migration rails creates an index by default. There should always be index on foreign keys. In case of polymorphic association it tries to create index on id and type column and in your case they both combined were too long. I hope this explains the issue.